# Swing concrete anchors moving

Tags: concrete, digging

I concreted in my children swingset about a month ago but the concrete has cracked and moving! I used a ready mix concrete that you just add water too. The swingset is metal but it’s moving a lot now as my littlest is a daredevil on it.
Can I do anything to reinforce it or do I have to dig it all up and start again?
Many thanks

Lizzi[image]

Comment: How thick was the concrete and what size(length x width)?

Comment: You don't necessarily have to dig up the old concrete; you could dig new holes 2-3 feet over and try again. You should consider adding a picture to your question or else it's difficult to provide help for your specific situation.

Comment: Can you provide a close-up shot of the anchor bolt assembly? You may have used the swing before the concrete has fully cured, which usually takes 21 days after placement to reach full strength unless high early strength concrete was used (not likely to get from the local retail stores). Also, it could be the embedment of the anchor bolt was too short, and it was pulled up/out from the fresh concrete.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I have added a picture, just from the comments I see I had no idea what I was doing. Yes definitely I only kept the children off it for 24 hours! I used blue circle ready mix all purpose concrete. The anchor part was just a hook to put into the ground i then just put the concrete on top.

Comment: if it's still stuck on the metal, dig out even more around it and fill with more concrete. Might drive a crooked stake or two in the hole before pouring to give it more than dirt and weight for anchoring.

Comment: How deep is the hole?

Comment: 1.  Explain problem to swinging kids.   2.  Dig out holes.   3.  Then kids work to make holes bigger and deeper.   Serious holes.   4a.  Augment ends of poles if you can with projections etc.  5.  Lots of concrete maybe with some rocks and brick ends to take up space.  Kids add rocks and brick ends to pool of concrete.  6.  Kids sign top of drying concrete & add handprints.  They have to stay off swing until it is solid.  7.  Kids will remember fixing swing and you will too.

Comment: Thank you that’s such a lovely idea, we will do it